# Gulp-Sass: Changes are not transferred to the frontend

Tags: javascript, jquery, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-sass

The following happens with my gulp-sass configuration:

When I execute the task, the .min.css is generated, but the changes are not visible in the frontend. Only after I manually go into the .min.css and save them, the changes in the frontend are visible.

This strange behavior has never happened to me. Can someone help me with this?

Here is my gulpfile.js:

```
    // Load plugins
    const autoprefixer = require("gulp-autoprefixer");
    const browsersync = require("browser-sync").create();
    const cleanCSS = require("gulp-clean-css");
    const gulp = require("gulp");
    const header = require("gulp-header");
    const plumber = require("gulp-plumber");
    const rename = require("gulp-rename");
    const sass = require("gulp-sass");
    const pkg = require("./package.json");

    sass.compiler = require('node-sass');


    // Copy third party libraries from /node_modules into /vendor
    gulp.task("vendor", function(cb) {
      // Bootstrap
      gulp
        .src([
          "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/**/*",
          "!./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-grid*",
          "!./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-reboot*"
        ])
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./files/theme/vendor/bootstrap"));

      // jQuery
      gulp
        .src([
          "./node_modules/jquery/dist/*",
          "!./node_modules/jquery/dist/core.js"
        ])
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./vendor/jquery"));

      cb();
    });


    function css(){
        return gulp.src('./files/theme/scss/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'}).on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(
          autoprefixer({
            browsers: ["last 2 versions"],
            cascade: false
          })
        )
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./files/theme/css'))
        .pipe(
          rename({
            suffix: ".min"
          })
        )
        .pipe(cleanCSS())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./files/theme/css"))
        .pipe(browsersync.stream());
    }

    // Tasks
    gulp.task("css", css);

    // BrowserSync
    function browserSync(done) {
      browsersync.init({
        server: {
          baseDir: "./files/theme"
        }
      });
      done();
    }

    // BrowserSync Reload
    function browserSyncReload(done) {
      browsersync.reload();
      done();
    }

    // Watch files
    function watchFiles() {
      gulp.watch("./files/theme/scss/**/*", css);
      gulp.watch("./files/theme/**/*.html", browserSyncReload);
      gulp.watch("./templates/*.html5", browserSyncReload);
    }

    gulp.task("default", gulp.parallel("vendor", css));

    // dev task
    gulp.task("dev", gulp.parallel(watchFiles, browserSync));
```